# OpenJPA cascade persist one-to-many with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, openjpa

I have the following entities:

**Invoice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "InvoiceID")
    private Long invoiceID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice")
    private List<Invoiceitem> invoiceitemCollection;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID", referencedColumnName = "CustomerID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    private Customer customerID;

    // getter/setter
}
```

**Invoiceitem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoiceitem")
public class Invoiceitem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected InvoiceitemPK invoiceitemPK;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @JoinColumn(name = "InvoiceID", referencedColumnName = "InvoiceID", insertable = false,         updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Invoice invoice;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ProductID", referencedColumnName = "ProductID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product productID;

    // getter/setter
}
```

**InvoiceItemPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class InvoiceitemPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ItemID" ,nullable=false)
    private long itemID;

    @Column(name = "InvoiceID", nullable=false)
    private long invoiceID;

    // getter/setter
}
```

It's 3-tier stand alone app, and I need to do following:
test 1. for each of 10-invoice add 10-invoiceitem
....
....

**STEP 1**, populate Invoice - Invoiceitem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < invoiceNumber; i++ ){
 // set invoice where invoiceNumber = 10, 100
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        String formatIn = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfi = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
        java.util.Date inDate = sdfi.parse("29-04-2011");
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(inDate.getTime());

        invoice.setCustomerID(newCust);
        invoice.setDate(sqlDate);
        // set Invoiceitem
        setInvoiceItem(prod, invItemNumber, invoice);

        saveInvoice(invoice);

}
```

method ***setInvoiceItem***,

```
 List<Invoiceitem> invoiceItemList = new ArrayList<Invoiceitem>();
for(int i = 0; i  < invItemNumber ; i++){
// set invoiceitem where invItemNumber = 10, 100
        Invoiceitem invoiceItem = new Invoiceitem();
        int quantity = new RandomGeneratorForInteger().generateRandomNumber(10);
        int genProductID = new   RandomGeneratorForInteger().generateRandomNumber(ProductCollectionOpenJPA.getProdIDLi().size());
        Long pid = (Long) ProductCollectionOpenJPA.getProdIDLi().get(genProductID);
        // set relation
        invoiceItem.setInvoice(invoice);
        invoiceItem.setProductID(prod = new Product(pid));
        invoiceItem.setQuantity(quantity);
        invoiceItemList.add(invoiceItem);
}
invoice.setInvoiceitemCollection(invoiceItemList);
```

I have generic DAO

```
 public void insert(E entity) {
  try {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        em.persist(entity);
      } catch (Exception e) {
       rollbackTransaction();
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

**STEP 2,**  **InvoiceService** - persit invoice

```
public String save(Invoice invoice) {
InvoiceDAO.log("saving Invoice---> InvoiceItem instance", Level.INFO, null);
    try {
        inDAO.beginTransaction();
    inDAO.insert(invoice);

        for (int i = 0; i < invoice.getInvoiceitemCollection().size(); i++) {
            InvoiceitemPK inItmPK = new InvoiceitemPK();

            inItmPK.setItemID(++i);
            inItmPK.setInvoiceID(invoice.getInvoiceID());

            invoice.getInvoiceitemCollection().get(i).setInvoiceitemPK(inItmPK);

       for (int i = 0; i < invoice.getInvoiceitemCollection().size(); i++) {
            inDAO.insert(invoice);

            }
          inDAO.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        InvoiceDAO.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, e);
        return "Invoice  are't  saved";
    }
    inDAO.closeEntityManager();
    InvoiceDAO.log("save successful", Level.INFO, null);
    return "Invoice successfuly saved";
}
```

Running applications are obtained by errors:
1. org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to assign id "domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem-null" to new instance "domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem@4fdf11" failed;
2. org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: cant-set-value

...

What is the best way to persist Invoice into DB?
Where  I made ​​a mistake, and how to correct?

Hi Rick,

Exception stack looks like this:

```
<openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: This operation failed for some instances.  See the nested exceptions array for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.throwNestedExceptions(BrokerImpl.java:2493)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2179)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1808)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:609)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignField(StateManagerImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1591)
    at domainopenjpa.Invoice.pcGetinvoiceID(Invoice.java)
...
Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2302)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2139)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: cant-set-value
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy.insert(HandlerFieldStrategy.java:132)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.insert(FieldMapping.java:623)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.insert(AbstractUpdateManager.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.populateRowManager(AbstractUpdateManager.java:162)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:76)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    ... 78 more
NestedThrowables:
<openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to assign id "domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem-null" to new instance "domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem@4fdf11" failed; there is already an object in the L1 cache with this id. You must delete this object (in a previous transaction or the current one) before reusing its id.  This error can also occur when a horizontally or vertically mapped classes uses auto-increment application identity and does not use a hierarchy of application identity classes.
FailedObject: domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem@4fdf11
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ManagedCache.assignObjectId(ManagedCache.java:193)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assignObjectId(BrokerImpl.java:4949)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setStateManager(BrokerImpl.java:4046)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assertObjectIdAssigned(StateManagerImpl.java:636)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.afterFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1084)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1808)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:609)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignField(StateManagerImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1591)
    at domainopenjpa.Invoice.pcGetinvoiceID(Invoice.java)
    at domainopenjpa.Invoice.getInvoiceID(Invoice.java:64)
```

New Exception stack:

```
<openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Encountered unmanaged object in persistent field "domainopenjpa.Invoice.invoiceitemCollection<element:class domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem>" during flush.  However, this field does not allow cascade persist. Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), or enable cascade-persist globally, or manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
FailedObject: domainopenjpa.Invoiceitem@939bdb
```

Answer (score 1):

## Open Jpa ArgumentException:

(by Yosi Lev)

I had the same problem with openJpa when inserting rows.
I got the following ArgumentException :

```
<openjpa-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1481680 nonfatal user error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: 
Field "com.server.beans.entities.BalanceDetail.id" of "BalanceDetail 
id=BalanceDetailPK [relevanceDate=........],
can not be set to "BalanceDetailPK [relevanceDate=........]" value.
               WHICH WAS THE SAME VALUE ..
```

The problem was the @Embeddable PK class BalanceDetailPK.
The @Columns were all generated (using eclipse) with "insertable=false, updatable=false"

```
@Column(name="RELEVANCE_DATE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private java.util.Date relevanceDate;

@Column(name="FND_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Long fndId;
```

Removing these attributes :

```
@Column(name="RELEVANCE_DATE")
private java.util.Date relevanceDate;

@Column(name="FND_ID")
private Long fndId;
```

just solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `public String save(Invoice invoice)` method. When you call `inDAO.insert(invoice);` that is persisting your Invoice and it is cascading to all InvoiceItems. **You shouldn't be modifying a primary key after you hand it over to OpenJPA.**

In your save method, you need to set the InvoiceItemPK prior to calling `inDAO.insert(invoice);`. Also, don't call `inDAO.insert(...)` for each invoceItem as they are already persisted due to the Cascade property that you set on the relationship `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice")`

Comment: Allright, but when I try to set InvoiceitemPK,  i got null for InvoiceID, InvoiceID autoincrement, and becouse of that I'm a trying to do on this way.

Comment: Gotcha. You could remove the Cascade.ALL and after calling persist(and probably flush) on your Invoice get the ID out to put into the InvoiceItem.

Comment: When I do following, I got exeption witch is shown above, **New Exception stack:**. First step change _@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice") into @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")_ , second,in method **Save( Invoice inv){** persist Invoice and getID, after that in for loop create InvoiceitemPK and for each InvoiceItem set InvoiceID and ItemID.